# Eclipse Milo read values for multiple/array of selective tags/nodeId's in one request

Tags: eclipse, opc-ua, milo

Currently, if I have to fetch data for 10 nodedId's, the code below is called 10 times..

```
if(client!=null){ DataValue value =client.readValue(0, TimestampsToReturn.Both, nodeId)
                        .get(); String tagStringValue =  value.getValue().getValue().toString(); }
```

Any, other way to fetch data for 10 tags in one request..

Answer (score 0):

Call `OpcUaClient#readValues` instead, which accepts a `List` of `NodeId` as one of its parameters.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Will try. Got busy with another project so the late reply.